# How does different forms of EXISTS() affect performance in MS Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, tuning, exists

I've been told that when checking for the existence of a row in a table, this will work:

`EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM....)`

but that a "better" way in regards to speed performance of the query would be to use this:

`EXISTS(SELECT TOP(1) NULL FROM......)`

I've searched online for anything that references this comparison and the only information I can find says that this is a personal preference and there actually is no performance gain of one over the other. There's always the "case by case" aspect of a question like this, but in general, is there any performance gain from using the second implementation of `EXISTS()` over the first one?

Comment: Looking at the query plan in both cases would give you a definitive answer to your question (unlike asking random people on the internets); have you tried generating the plans? Ideally, you should have asked the person who told you that to provide proof.

Comment: TOP 1 and DISTINCT are discarded by the optimizer when you use EXISTS or NOT EXISTS anyway. You should probably exact revenge on whomever told you that.

Comment: As said, to be 100% certain compare the plans. I remember this making some difference back in SQL2000 days. Later versions of the optimiser are more efficient in such checks.

Comment: Inside an exists you can even use select * with zero impact. It only checks for the existence of rows. The columns in the query are discarded. You can even do crazy stuff like "exists(select 1/0 from..." and it works just fine. :P

Comment: @SeanLange Not *always* true.... https://dbfiddle.uk/ui2Lq5aH

Comment: @Charlieface In your example you use id/0 and not 1/0 that is different, try tu use what Sean Lange said, 1/0 and you'll get no error

Comment: @sepupic Works for `OFFSET FETCH` but not for `INTERSECT` https://dbfiddle.uk/XIsB1dKL

Comment: @Charlieface The question was about the existence of row in a table , but you changed it and search for evaluated value that is different

Comment: @Charlieface that is because when you use the intersect it has to actually evaluate the rows values so it will raise the exception. In a basic select statement it doesn't have to do that.

Comment: @SeanLange I know *why* it happens, I was just saying it's not a blanket statement that `exists (select 1/0` always works.

Comment: @Charlieface true...as with anything sql server the only truly blanket statement is "it depends". LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be sure, you would have to check the execution plans.

But it's almost certain, given how trivial an optimization it is, that the compiler will always discard the following in the top level of an `EXISTS`, as they do not affect the semantics:

- All `SELECT` columns
- `DISTINCT`
- `TOP`
- `ORDER BY`

All you are doing is looking to see if there is *any* row, and none of these constructs can reduce it to zero.

Note that this isn't *always* true: there are some constructs that will interact and preserve some of those features because of their semantics. For example:

- `OFFSET FETCH`
- `INTERSECT/EXCEPT` (but not `UNION`)
- [Column-level permissions](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2020/01/24/actual-difference-between-existsselect-1-existsselect-and-existsselect-column/), if they exist on that table, mean you need to select only from a column that you have permission on, rather than `SELECT NULL`.

---

Common practice is to use either `SELECT 1` or `SELECT NULL`.

For clarity, I always write an `EXISTS` with the `SELECT` on the same line and the `FROM` on the next, showing that the `SELECT` is really just syntax, like this:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM SomeTable
```

In some DBMSs, you can even leave out the columns completely

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT
    FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reading my question and providing such a clearly explained and thorough answer! I will take this information and do some in depth testing myself, I asked this question because I had done some initial research, as my question stated, and was only able to come up with references that said there is no difference but didn't provide any substance to back that up. Upvoted and marked as accepted answer. THANK YOU!